# Telegram JNI Detects Error in application : thread thread after changing the max_account_count from both UserConfig and defines.h

Tags: android, java-native-interface, telegram

I tried to download the telegram source from their official git repository. My app compiles and runs perfectly fine with the original code.

Now, I want to modify the maximum accounts in telegram from 3 to 5 suppose. So, I changed the `MAX_ACCOUNT_COUNT` in `UserConfig` to 5 and also in `defines.h` to 5, but I'm getting a runtime JNI error in thread:

> 05-09 14:34:29.948 21639-21655/org.telegram.messenger E/FA: ?>AppMeasurementReceiver not registered/enabled
>   05-09 14:34:29.948 21639-21655/org.telegram.messenger E/FA: AppMeasurementService not registered/enabled
>   05-09 14:34:29.948 21639-21655/org.telegram.messenger E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[35,tid=21722,Native,Thread*=0x9c135a00,peer=0x130b80a0,"Thread-93784"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[35,tid=21722,Native,Thread*=0x9c135a00,peer=0x130b80a0,"Thread-93784"]
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallStaticVoidMethodV
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "Thread-93784" prio=10 tid=35 Runnable
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x130b80a0 self=0x9c135a00
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=21722 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9acd6930
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0x9abda000-0x9abdc000 stackSize=1014KB
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 0035b179  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+116)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0033bfdb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEP12BacktraceMap+146)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0024ee4d  /system/lib/libart.so (*ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2*+752)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0024f4ef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+54)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000fbabd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+28)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 00100851  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE.constprop.95+4780)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 0010e7c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_listNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+636)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 0010f0c7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+26)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 00197704  /data/app/org.telegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.30.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv20CallStaticVoidMethodEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+52)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 0026d8b4  /data/app/org.telegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.30.so (_ZN18ConnectionsManager6selectEv+3028)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 00278c84  /data/app/org.telegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.30.so (_ZN18ConnectionsManager10ThreadProcEPv+280)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 0003fe37  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 0001a56d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   (no managed stack frames)
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] 
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:368] Runtime aborting...
>   05-09 14:34:31.243 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:368] 
>   05-09 14:34:31.248 21639-21722/org.telegram.messenger A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 21722 (Thread-93784)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

change the ConnectionsManager& ConnectionsManager::getInstance(int32_t instanceNum) in ConnectionsManager.cpp

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: every account needs a ConnectionsManager instance so if you increase the maximum accounts in telegram from 3 to 5, you should create two more ConnectionsManager instances